# Optimize Mysql for table 4.000.000 records

Tags: mysql, optimization, where-clause

I have one table with 4.000.000 records.

and i want to run single query to select male member

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE gender='0' ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 0,20;
```

it took 12 seconds to do this query.
i already have INDEX with gender,member_id field.
0: male
1: female

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Field   Cardinality
gender  BTREE   No  No  gender  2
```

so, how can i speed up this query :(

Comment: what type did you use for `gender` field?

Comment: how fast is it if you just select member_id instead of *

Comment: How fast is your HD and maybe you conf/ram can be changed. Are you sure I have a 3million record table and something like that (i did `t=32`) took me ~3seconds. Perhaps its due to order by. With that many entries it does take a few seconds. Also maybe your pulling a blob? maybe select less things? also what iouri said

Comment: @Aif gender field is tinyint(1) , i just tried with enum(0,1) but no beter

Comment: @TomSawyer can you try a `SELECT * FROM member where gender = 0` rather than `gender = '0'`?

Answer (score 2):

You need an index with 2 fields:
gender, member_id DESC

That should speed it up to a fraction of a sec.

The SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE  myTable ADD INDEX (  `gender` ,  `memcber_id` DESC )
```

Comment: Is this table locked due to other queries?

Comment: Perhaps also try recreating the index, sometimes an index may have a bad day :)

Comment: -1: This is a bad idea, esp. since if the query engine decides it cannot use an index on `gender` due to low cardinality, you will also lose indexing on `member_id`.

Comment: @RedFilter what do you mean lose index on member_id? Are you saying the DB will say screw it, i can index member_id but wont because i was told to index gender too? Will it remove an already existing index on it as well? I doubt either would happen

Comment: @acidzombie24 If the order of columns in a single index is `gender` and then `member_id`, and the db decides a `gender` index won't help, then it cannot use the `member_id` data in the same index separately, because it is not in order, only ordered according to `gender`, which is not being used.

Comment: @RedFilter huh? Aren't indexes of a row independent of eachother? and since when did he say he wanted to order by gender... Its just random rows that will be a gender specific and... actually i don't know. Maybe it would opt by optimizing by group then filter the gender w/o using an index? I have no idea anymore.

Comment: @acidzombie24 1) *Aren't indexes of a row independent of each other* Columns are indexed, not rows. 2) *when did he say he wanted to order by gender* I am talking about the ordered list of values in an index, not the SQL `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: @RedFilter yeah i realized that halfway through writing that which is why I have no idea how it would be optimized. I suspect its just grouping by then going through everything checking the gender. So your saying this is useless because both can't be used at once

Answer (score 1):

Try just indexing `member_id`. The low [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29) for `gender` means the index on that column will not be helpful. This is lilely going to be a slow query no matter what, though, unless you can add additional filters to the `WHERE` clause.

For more info, see: [What makes a good MySQL index? Part 2: Cardinality](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-2-cardinality/)

Comment: tks, that's right. only 2 on cardinality. so nothing can speed up this query? because there's to gender (0: male , 1: female)

Comment: Well, it actually depends on the data distribution. E.g., if almost all are `0` and you search for `1`, an index could help. For more info, see the link I added above.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it SHOULD take this long. Why don't you just scan parts of it by either scanning only 100K rows at a time (don't use limit, that doesn't help). You may even want to split things up by date (which would be indexed).

You should just use chucks. You don't need all of it at once anyways. Also you may not have enough ram for keys/important data. Here is actual code I wrote today

```
var offsetStep=5000;
for(int offset=0; offset<countOrMax; offset+=offsetStep)
{
    using (var tns = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var res = conn.Query<long>("select id from table1 where id>=@l and id<@u and t=@t", new { u = offset + offsetStep, l = offset, t = blah });
        //work with chuck
```